# install extra compiz plugins (burn) and (groups & tabs)

Tags: compiz, 12.10

How to install these plugins in ubuntu 12.10 ?
I watched some videos for installation and using them ,but I didnt find any thing  !

help please

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install the compizconfig-settings-manager, compiz-plugins-extra, and of coarse compiz. All available in the repository through the software center or synaptic. Once installed you can select the "extras" that you want enabled. Watch the tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCV6fNjq1Ws)

BTW when you install compiz it will pull in a lot of extra packages. Just let it. You will need them to run.

****since the first half of my answer isn't working for you I will edit this to include another option*** *

Remove the two .HIDDEN files in your `~/HOME directory, .compiz-1 and .compiz` then log out or reboot. To verify that these are indeed the correct files....open your file manager> in your ~/HOME directory> Ctrl+h which will show your hidden files. You may have the option to rename them or make a backup by opening a terminal and use this CLI:

`sudo mv ~/.compiz-1 ~/.compiz-1_old`

and

`sudo mv ~/.compiz ~/.compiz_old`

REBOOT

Comment: That what I did , and I didn't find some extra plugins like groups and taps ...

Comment: Compiz WIKI for advise. http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Group  beyond that your machine may have conflicting settings or all the dependences not met for them to work. Check your CCSM settings, mouse and keyboard.

Comment: I was using that effect in Ubuntu 12.04 on the same machine , I read Compiz wiki too .. this is a screen shot:  http://ubuntuone.com/6RSWRLfXwQzjjqT9yZ4lXY

What I have to do to get it ?

Comment: @StarDiamond I edited the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry it didnt work :(  ,...  thank you for your answers

Comment: @StarDiamond , may have found an answer for you.....THEY DON'T EXIST IN THE CURRENT 12.10 REPOSITORY.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 12.10 with mate i was able to get a few of the extras to work. Downloaded the addons script from gnome-looks. Right now im working on figuring out what exactally needs to be changed for this to work on 12.10 gnome fallback session. As of now I can compile the addons fine but get ld -ign errors when installing. After the script runs i can see Freely transformable windows, wizard and Anaglyph in ccsm but once i enable them ccsm kills itself.